# Google Cloud Platform AutoML prediction interval showing 0 as min and max

Tags: model, regression, google-cloud-automl, google-prediction

I train a regression model using GCP AutoML tables and I can make batch predictions as well as online ones. But I need the prediction interval that is always showing me 0 as min and max value. I retrained the model again but it's still not showing me the prediction interval. My previous model works fine and I have the prediction interval but when I trained the model with a new dataset I'm getting now this issue with the new model.

Any help?

Thanks

Comment: Are you retrieving your results in Cloud Storage?

Comment: I finally succeeded to get the lower and upper bounds of the prediction interval by retraining my model using MAE and 5 hours process time instead of RMSE and 3 hours. I was retrieving my results in Bigquery. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The issue was resolved by retraining the model using MAE and 5 hours process time instead of RMSE and 3 hours. The results were retrieved in Bigquery.